# logo on building

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

I have a company logo i would like to photoshop on a building for a promotional ad. The problem is that when i put the logo on the building it doesn't look very real, it should look like its painted on the building and then a photo was taken but for the moment i just looks like a picture of the building with a logo photoshopped on it.

With the warp tool i can get it in to the right shape but its not really what it should be, any tips on how i can create this effect?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you post the logo and the building, then i can create it for you and give you the psd + explenation for future reference. 1 thing you surely should do to make it more realistic is add a little noise and take a good look at the lighting.

Comment: Not the actual logo and building but the idea reamins the same, getting the logo on the brick wall.  http://media.dexigner.com/article/18586/Harris_A_Smith_Building_02.jpg  http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_t_aBPSZQizw/TEcgiqCW09I/AAAAAAAAA4A/WAW0dvK-zkw/s1600/starbucks-logo.gif

Answer (score 11):

I just started a new blog, so i decided to make [a little tutorial on this](http://www.luukratief-design.nl/tutorials/placing-a-logo-on-a-building/).

Here is the result:
[image]

How it is done:

- Put the logo layer on the background and set blending mode to overlay or multiply (depends on the logo).
- Now hit CTRL+T or go to Edit > Free transform
- Adjust the anchorpoints as shown in the image below:
  [image]
- You could play a little with the opacity of the logo layer. Whatever looks best
- Pad your back, since you just put the logo on the wall. Go you!

Comment: An additional advice could be to play with soft edges: `[Ctrl/Strg] + click` on layer. Then `[Ctrl] + [D]` and select a radius. Then add a layer mask to blend with those soft edges. Normally that helps merging it with the background a little better.

Comment: Good adition there!

Answer (score 6):

This kind of composite requires two steps: a) get the perspective and form correct, and b) use blend modes and/or opacity adjustments to make it look real.

### Perspective and Form

Use the Free Transform tool for simple perspective adjustments.

Use the Vanishing Point filter for trickier situations, or where it has to look exactly right based on the perspective lines in the image.

Where the surface is curved, bumpy or is otherwise clearly not flat, create a Displacement Map from the best-contrast channel and use Filter > Distort > Displace to distort the image in a way that follows the contours of the image. Sometimes a combination of Free Transform and Displacement are necessary. See [this question and its answers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3492/how-to-show-background-texture-through-text-placed-on-background-in-photoshop) for more on this subject.

### Blending the Composite

Sometimes, as in this case, switching to a blend mode such as Overlay or Multiply, or slightly reducing the opacity of the "add-on" will be all you need to do. It very much depends on the two images.

When you have it close to what you need, carefully check the lighting and texture. You may need to add a subtle highlight or shadow to make it real.

Answer (score 1):

Align the logo with the wall,

Change mode to `Overlay` -- `Duplicate layer`

place the duplicated layer behind the original layer and give it a `Gaussian Blur`

Should work.

Rework, till it looks real.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Watercolor filter

> Filter>Artistic>Watercolor

Then try playing with the `Emboss` in `Blending Options`

Comment: i'm not really looking for a paint effect, just that the texture and shapes of the building transfer on to the logo so it looks more real.